# Wagtail - issue with streamfields off the page?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Has anyone had this issue in Wagtail 2.10.1 where the streamfields seem to be going off the page and under the grey side bar cutting off the left hand side of all the fields?

I've attached an image to show what I'm going on about:

[Streamfields going off the left hand side under the grey bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYpcC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6347#issuecomment-678672024 , this can happen if you've defined your panel as `StreamFieldPanel("some_field", classname="full")`. Removing `classname="full"` should fix it.

Comment: Perfect! You are a star, how did I miss that!